# How to sniff websocket traffic with wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, websocket

-1
Hi!

My phone has a remote control application that controls my stb. I would like to sniff websocket traffic in between.
My pc is connected by ethernet interface to local network
I know the port used, the local ip address of my phone, the local ip address of my stb.

When I use wireshark on windows , I don't see anything as soon as I apply a filter on the previous elements.

(If I fliter by websocket protocol, I just see ping pong between my pc and my router)

Can you help me ? Thanks